# Why Huffman Coding is good?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, huffman-code

I am **not** asking how Huffman coding is working, but instead, I want to know why it is good.

I have the following two questions:

**Q1**

I understand the ultimate purpose of Huffman coding is to give certain char a less bit number, so space is saved. What I don't understand is that why the decision of number of bits for a char can be related to the char's frequency?

[Huffman Encoding Trees](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node41.html) says

> It is sometimes advantageous to use variable-length codes, in which
>   different symbols may be represented by different numbers of bits. For
>   example, Morse code does not use the same number of dots and dashes
>   for each letter of the alphabet. In particular, E, the most frequent
>   letter, is represented by a single dot.

So in Morse code, E can be represented by a single dot because it is the most frequent letter. But why? Why can it be a dot just because it is most frequent?

**Q2**

Why the probability / statistics of the chars are so important to Huffman coding?

What happen if the statistics table is wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199383/what-are-the-real-world-applications-of-huffman-coding for a answer on application of huffman code

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a more conceptual question and should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: A good answer to this question would not involve much in the way of programming and that this question is off-topic.  I think that the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_code) provides the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign less number or bits or **shorter code** words for **most frequently** used symbols you will be saving a lot of storage space.

Suppose you want to assign 26 unique codes to English alphabet and want to store an english  novel ( only letters ) in term of these code you will require less memory if you assign short length codes to most frequently occurring characters.

You might have observed that postal code and STD codes for important cities are usually shorter ( as they are used very often ). This is very fundamental concept in **Information theory**.

Huffman encoding gives prefix codes.

**Construction of Huffman tree:**

A greedy approach to construct Huffman tree for `n` characters is as follows:

places `n` characters in n sub-trees. 
Starts by combining the two least weight nodes into a tree which is assigned the sum of the two leaf node weights as the weight for its root node.
Do this until you get a single tree.

For example consider below binary tree where E and T have high weights ( as very high occurrence )

[image]

It is a prefix tree. To get the Huffman code for any character, start from the node corresponding to the the character and backtrack till you get the root node.

Comment: could you please update your answer to explain why the building algorithm of huffman codes can build a prefix tree?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, an E *could* be, say, three dashes followed by two dots. When you make your own encoding, you get to decide. If your goal is to encode a certain text so that the result is as short as possible, you *should* choose short codes for the most frequent characters. The Huffman algorithm ensures that we get the optimal codes for a specific text.

If the frequency table is somehow wrong, the Huffman algorithm will still give you a valid encoding, but the encoded text would be longer than it could have been if you had used a correct frequency table. This is usually not a problem, because we usually create the frequency table based on the actual text that is to be encoded, so the frequency table will be "perfect" for the text that we are going to encode.

Answer (score 1):

well.. you want assign shorter codes to the symbols which appear more frequently... huffman encoding works just by this simple assumption.. :-)

you compute the frequency of all symbols, sort them all, and start assigning bit codes to each one.. the more frequent a symbol is, the shorter the code you'll assign to it.. simple as this.

the big question is: how large the window in which we compute such frequencies should be? should it be as large as the entire file? or should it be smaller? and if the latter apply, how large? Most huffman encoding have some sort of "test-run" in which they estimate the best window size a little bit like TCP/IP do with its windows frame sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Huffman codes provide two benefits:

1. they are space efficient given some corpus
2. they are prefix codes

Given some set of documents for instance, encoding those documents as Huffman codes is the most space efficient way of encoding them, thus saving space. This however only applies to that set of documents as the codes you end up are dependent on the probability of the tokens/symbols in the original set of documents. The statistics are important because the symbols with the highest probability (frequency) are given the shortest codes. Thus the symbols most likely to be in your data use the least amount of bits in the encoding, making the coding efficient.

The prefix code part is useful because it means that no code is the prefix of another. In morse code for instance `A = dot dash` and `J = dot dash dash dash`, how do you know where to break reading the code. This increases the inefficiency of transmitting data using morse as you need a special symbol (pause) to signify the end of transmission of one code. Compare that to Huffman codes where each code is unique, as soon as you discover the encoding for a symbol in the input, you know that that is the transmitted symbol because it is guaranteed **not** to be the prefix of some other symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It's the dual effect of having the *most frequent characters* using *the shortest bit sequences* that gives you the savings.

For a concrete example, let's say you have a piece of text that consists of 1024 `e` characters and 1024 of all other characters combined.

With 8 bits for code, that's a full 2048 bytes used in uncompressed form.

Now let's say we represent `e` as a single 1-bit and every other letter as a 0-bit followed by  its original 8 bits (a very primitive form of Huffman).

You can see that half the characters have been expanded from 8 bits to 9, giving 9216 bits, or 1152 bytes. However, the `e` characters have been reduced from 8 bits to 1, meaning they take up 1024 bits, or 128 bytes.

The total bytes used is therefore 1152 + 128, or 1280 bytes, representing a compression ratio of 62.5%.

You can use a fixed encoding scheme based on the likely frequencies of characters (such as English text), or you can use adaptive Huffman encoding which changes the encoding scheme as characters are processed and frequencies are adjusted. While the former may be okay for input which has high probability of matching frequencies, the latter can adapt to any input.

Answer (score 0):

Statistic table can't be wrong, because in general Huffman algorithm, analyze hole text at the beginning, and builds frequent-statistics of the given text, while Morse has a static symbol -code map.

Huffman algorithm uses the advantage of a given text. As an example, if E is most frequent letter in English in general, that doesn't mean that E is most frequent in a given text for a given author.

Another advantage of Huffman algorithm is that you can use it for any alphabet starting from [0, 1] finished Chinese hieroglyphs, while Morse is defined only for English letters

Answer (score 0):

1. So in Morse code, "E" can be represented by a single dot, because it is the most frequent letter. But why? Why is it a dot because of its frequency?
   "E" can be encoded to any unique code for a specific code dictionary, so it can be "0", we choose it to be short to save memory, so the average bytes used after encode is minimized.
2. Why is the probability / statistics of the chars so important to Huffman coding? What happens if the statistics table is wrong?
   why do we encode? save space right?　Space used after encode is freq(wordi)*Length(wordi), it is what we should try to minimize, so we choose to assign words with high prob short code greedly to save space.
   If the statistics table is wrong, then the encoding is not the best way to save space.